# How to remove numbers between brackets and a slash between them in jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, numbers, character

I have a long list of strings as follows

```
Corporate Docs (Only papers) - Paris (45/9833)
```

I want the strings as

```
Corporate Docs (Only papers) - Paris
```

(without the brackets and back slash and numbers)

I have tried to remove numbers first and then the remaining part like this

```
childItem.replace(/\d+/g, '');
childItem.replace('(/)', '');
```

But no luck. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the regex

```
/\([\s\d\/]+\)/
```

and replace with empty string

```
var str = "Corporate Docs (Only papers) - Paris (45/9833)";
console.log(str.replace(/\([\s\d\/]+\)/, "")
               .trim()); // trim to remove the last space if any
```